# Where does @mime_partial come from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `.rhtml` file and there are many condition checks like this `<% if @mime_partial %>` This condition is used before using html tags.

I'm working on action mailer. I'm redesigning the view, the code is written by my friend. In the browser one can click the button to "send email".

The variable `@mime_partial` is defined no where. I thought it's an internal thing of Rails.

What is the significance of this `mime_partial`?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I used grep and got this:

```
xyz.merge!(:mime_partial => true, .... )
```

It has never been set to false, then why are they using if condition on it?

Answer:

I found out the answer.

this `@mime_partial` corresponds to `mailer`. When I render the view in browser, it will be controlled by controller not mailer, so `@mime_partial` will be `false`.

When I render the content by sending email, then in email the `@mime_partial` will be set to `true`, because it is controlled by mailer not controller. Then it will render some new contents which were inside the if condition.

thanks for the support.

Comment: Could you please put us in the context what you're doing? Did you write this yourself or what Rails project are you looking at?

Comment: From the view extension (.rhtml) I am guessing that your project is in Rails 1. But could you check the version of Rails your project is in?

Comment: ok grep actually worked and i see it is used like this xyz.merge!(:mime_partial => true, .... )

Comment: but mime_partial has never been set to false. why are they checking if condtion with this ??

Comment: @max: How can we know that? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably your controller is creating this instance variable. You may grep your sources and see where this variable is used.

I don't see this variable in Rails 1.x sources, so I believe it is something specific to your application. But it may be, that this variable is created by some gem or plugin.

```
cd your/rails_app && grep -r 'mime_partial' .
```

Comment: ok grep actually worked and i see it is used like this xyz.merge!(:mime_partial => true, .... )

Comment: Now you should trace the use of this object `xyz` - maybe it's later used to create that instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about what you exactly are working on it's impossible to guess what that means.

However, the general thing is that you have something like this:

```
<% if @mime_partial %>
    some stuff here that only gets rendered if @mime_partial is true
<% end %>
```

In short, if `@mime_partial` is not set to true, then the stuff inside the if will not be included in the output (page).

Comment: i am working on action mailer. i am redesigning the view, the code is written by my friend. in the browser one can click the button to "send email".

the variable @mime_partial is defined no where. i thought its a internal thing of rails

Comment: It's not part of Rails 1.x. Easiest is to ask your friend :) Maybe he just forgot to remove it as the code changed?